# How do I get to my Azure Repository and see files online?

Tags: azure-devops, repository, azure-repos

I've had a TFS account since time immemorial, but haven't accessed it in a couple years.  I knew it moved to Azure Repositories, but when you sign into the DevOps site I don't see source control, repositories, TFS anywhere.  I need to pull down my code.  I have local copies of code but latest was in TFS.  Anyone have a URL for logging in?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I get to my Azure Repository and see files online?

If you confirm that your account is migrated to azure devops services, please try to access the Azure DevOps Profile Page:

https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?

And try switching between different directories to check if you could found your organization:

[image]

And if you still could not found your organization in the all directories, you need to make sure if you account have been added to the new Azure Repository.